# How to shorten my code with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My task is what I have done but I am wondering about if the select box is not only three options... If they are 5 or 10 options so let's imagine that how the `if else` condition below can be...

More than that, after choosing another option, the others option's `input` will be **returned to no value** as my code.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/7us66/7/)**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td></tr>
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="select_vehicle">
            <option value="company_vehicle">Company Vehicle</option>
            <option value="hiring_vehicle">Hiring Vehicle</option>
            <option value="taxi">Taxi</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="company_vehicle">
    <td>Company Vehicle</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="bus" />Bus</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="train" />Trolley Car</td>
</tr>
<tr id="hiring_vehicle">
    <td>Hiring Vehicle</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="bus" />Bus</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="train" />Trolley Car</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="taxi">
    <td>Taxi</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Taxi" />Taxi
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
<tr><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var select_vehicle = $("#select_vehicle");
// Set selected item
var set_selected_item = $(select_vehicle).val("company_vehicle");
// Hide options "Hiring Vehicle" & "Taxi"
var company_vehicle = $("#company_vehicle"); // Get id "Company Vehicle"
var hiring_vehicle = $("#hiring_vehicle"); // Get id "Hiring Vehicle"
hiring_vehicle.hide();
var taxi = $("#taxi"); // Get id "Taxi"
taxi.hide();

$(select_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
if (valueSelected == "company_vehicle") {
    company_vehicle.show();
    hiring_vehicle.hide();
    taxi.hide();
    $("#taxi input").removeAttr('checked');
    $("#hiring_vehicle input").removeAttr('checked').val("");
} else if (valueSelected == "hiring_vehicle") {
    company_vehicle.hide();
    hiring_vehicle.show();
    taxi.hide();
    $("#company_vehicle input").removeAttr('checked').val("");
    $("#taxi input").removeAttr('checked');
} else {
    company_vehicle.hide();
    hiring_vehicle.hide();
    taxi.show();
    $("#company_vehicle input").removeAttr('checked').val("");
    $("#hiring_vehicle input").removeAttr('checked').val("");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#select_vehicle').change(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $('#'+val).find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    $('#'+val).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked',false);
    $('#'+val).show().siblings('tr[id]').hide();    
}).change();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7us66/9/)**

Comment: Thank you for your code. However, Will the others option's `input` be **returned to no value**, after choosing another option as my code.

Comment: That works well at all. I just add more code for the `type[checkbox]` as http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/7us66/11/. Am I correct? Anyway thank you very much :-)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct, or shorten your code using `$('#'+val).find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('checked',false);`: http://jsfiddle.net/7us66/12/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value of `$("#select_vehicle")` to dynamically get the id of the element to show. In the HTML add the class `select_option` to all of the `tr`'s that are option holders like:

```
<tr id="company_vehicle" class="select_option">
    <td>Company Vehicle</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="bus" />Bus</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="train" />Trolley Car</td>
</tr>
<tr id="hiring_vehicle" class="select_option">
    <td>Hiring Vehicle</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="bus" />Bus</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="train" />Trolley Car</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="taxi" class="select_option">
    <td>Taxi</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Taxi" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
```

Javscipt:

```
$("#select_vehicle").on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;

    $('.select_option').hide();
    $('.select_option input[type="text"]').val('');
    $('.select_option input:checked').prop('checked', false);

    $('#'+valueSelected).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: That's great. I have tried that but it didn't work with the **selectbox**

Comment: @PMay1903 it should work fine if you make sure you give the correct `tr`s the class `select_option`. If it doesn't let me know.

Comment: It makes me quite confused. Could you please give me a demonstration as a JSFiddle link? Anyhow I appreciate your help and I will send you a reputation if I can learn a new method as your interesting idea.